# Cannot get owned object by cloning it

Tags: rust

I have a reference to a vector of structs. I want to create a reference of an enumerated vector with given structs (but not struct references). I do a `clone()` to obtain the new instances but it doesn't seem to work. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```rust
struct Item {
    name: String,
}

fn get_enumerated(data: &Vec<Item>) -> Vec<(usize, Item)> {
    data.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, item)| (i, item.clone()))
        .collect()
}
```

The error I get is:

```rust
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<(usize, Item)>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `(usize, &Item)`
 --> src/lib.rs:9:10
  |
9 |         .collect()
  |          ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<(usize, Item)>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=(usize, &Item)>`
  |
  = help: the trait `FromIterator<(usize, &Item)>` is not implemented for `Vec<(usize, Item)>`
```

It doesn't matter how many clones I'll put there, even if I'll duplicate the line with `map()` multiple times, it's still a reference.

Why the `clone()` doesn't work here? And how do I change the reference to an owned object here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the clone derive on your struct, so it is just cloning the reference to it:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Item {
    name: String,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8967c5f09ac3eab075a9e74fbb2b2506)

Comment: Oh, what a silly mistake. Thanks!